# Why isn't $S^1$ contractible in homotopy type theory?

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

$\newcommand\base{\mathit{base}}\newcommand\unique{\mathit{unique}}\DeclareMathOperator\transport{transport}\newcommand\loop{\mathit{loop}}\DeclareMathOperator\refl{refl}$In the context of homotopy type theory, I am trying to prove that the only element of $S^1$ is $\base$ i.e. $\unique: \prod_{x:S^1} \base=x$ however by using the induction principle of the circle I reach a dead end:

$$P: S^1 \rightarrow \mathcal{U}; P \mathrel{:\equiv} x \Rightarrow \base=x.$$

For induction, it is required an element $a: P(\base)$ and a path $l: \transport^P(\loop, a) = a$ that by transport over path spaces results in $l: a \cdot \loop = a$.

Choosing $a \mathrel{:\equiv} \refl_{\base}$ or $a \mathrel{:\equiv} \loop$ results on impossible paths (assuming univalence) i.e. $l: \loop = \refl_{\base}$ and $l: \loop \cdot \loop = \loop$.

This made me think if $S^1$ have other elements other than base? or there is some other path $a: \base = \base$ that makes $l$ be derivable, but which ones?

Comment: The circle is connected, but not contractable. That is, everything of type $S^1$ is *merely* equal to base, but the statement you're trying to prove is false.

Comment: Wow, I don't understand this question at all.

Comment: Nor do I. (But at least the question has the correct spelling of "contractible".)

Comment: I would like to improve the question, any suggestions?

Comment: I would be curious to hear whether the close vote is the result of fear of the unknown, or a HoTT expert thinking this question is too basic for MO (which it is).

Comment: I think it would help if you started out with a little bit of exposition -- like "In the context of homotopy type theory". As it is at first the question sounded like a "not even wrong" kind of question to me. Only after seeing Andrej Brauer's comment and the HoTT tag did I realize this is just taking about objects I (thought I) know in a context I am completely unfamiliar with.

Comment: As @AndrejBauer says, this question is very far from research-level — it would be a much better fit on [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) than here.  Voted to migrate. // @ Daniel: I think the short suggestion/answer is that your intuition either for what “contractible” means, or for what adding paths does, is not quite right.

Comment: HoTT is well beyond the standard graduate syllabus which a mathematician should be expected to know; there are many many of us who don't understand it. I don't think we should be closing down questions about how to do basic things in HoTT on the grounds that they are obvious to people who know HoTT.

Comment: The argument for sending it to math.stackexchange is not that basic things in HoTT are off topic, it's that a research mathematician should know that the circle is not contractible. (The question has since been edited and is now ok.)

Comment: I want to apologize for my rude comment. I don't think there's anything wrong with the question; the problem is my own lack of understanding. Still, it's amazing how different things can sound, in language that is not familiar. Perhaps this is how my students feel when I talk about things that they are still learning.

Comment: If the circle were contractible, then "contractible" would not be a great choice of for that property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this will help: in homotopy type theory, to say that $x$ and $y$ of type $A$ are *different* corresponds intuitively to the fact that they are in different connected components, i.e., there is no path between them.

Specifically, for the circle $S^1$:

- The statement $\Pi(x, y: S^1).\, x = y$ ("All points are equal") should be understood geometrically as saying that there is a *continuous* map which to each pair of points assigns a path between them.
- The statement $\Sigma(x, y : S^1).\, x \neq y$ ("There are two different points") should be understood as saying that there are points on the circle which are not connected by a path.

Neither of the above is the case. What *is* the case, though is that $\Pi (x, y : S^1) . \|x = y\|_{-1}$ ("Every two points are in the same connectedness component.")

Comment: This answer brings me some ideas (correct me if I am misunderstanding): I cannot prove the first case, since the function itself could raise paths that will conflict in some way with univalence. By truncating it, we deny this possibility and make it consistent. Something similar as the case of LEM, where we can assume it consistently if we truncate it to only mere propositions.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit like that.

Comment: That should either be $\| x = y \|_{-1}$ or $\| x \|_0 = \| y \|_0$.

Comment: @NaïmFavier: thanks, fixed. By the way, you can just edit people's answers around here.

Comment: I know, but I didn't know which one you meant precisely! (Not that it matters, as they are equivalent.)

Answer (score 5):

The question was answered by Noah Snyder [in the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454548/is-s1-contractible#comment1176601_454548): No, $S^1$ is not contractible.

It connected, so any point in $S^1$ is merely equal to $base$.

To prove that $S^1$ is not contractible, you might try proving that the identity type $base = base$ is equivalent to $\mathbb Z$, e.g. via the [encode-decode method](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/encode-decode+method).

Comment: I understand that the type $base=base$ is not contractible because different elements can be generated from loop and concatenation. But if $S^1$ is not contractible, I would expect something similar to its path space, i.e. building some sort of non-trivial points that are different from base. How the non-trivial path loop can affect the fact that there is only one point, i.e. base?

Comment: The nontrivial loop does not affect the fact that there merely is only one point. It's possible to merely have only one point and not be contractible. This is homotopy type theory, after all.

Comment: By "merely" you refer to propositional truncation?

Comment: Yes, "merely" is the terminology from the [HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/). Speaking of which, have you not looked at  it? Chapter 6 begins with a detailed explanation of what is going on with the circle, with pictures in color.

Comment: Yes, I have read it many times and this question comes as an attempt to understand it more.