A contradiction involving HoTT function extensionality in higher inductive types
I'm having difficulty resolving what seems to be a contradiction between two lemmas in the HoTT Book and am seeking help to determine where I'm going wrong. Below, all types may be higher inductive types.
In the HoTT book, Lemma 6.2.9 states: For any type $A$ we have a natural equivalence $$ (\mathbb{S}^1 \to A) \simeq \sum_{x : A} (x = x)$$ Meanwhile, Lemma 6.3.2 states: If $f,g \colon A \to B$ are two functions such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x : A$, then $f = g$ in the type $A \to B$.
My contradiction is this.  Lemma 6.2.9 implies the existence of distinct maps of type $\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ because $\sum_{x : \mathbb{S}^1} (x=x)$ is $\mathtt{base} = \mathtt{base}$ which contains $\mathtt{loop}^n$ for $n : \mathbb{N}$. However, Lemma 6.3.2 says these maps are necessarily equal because, given any two of those maps $f$ and $g$, we have
$f(\mathtt{base}) = g(\mathtt{base})$.
Where does my reasoning fail?

$f(\mathtt{base}) = g(\mathtt{base})$ does not imply $\forall (x : \mathbb{S}^1). f(x) = g(x)$, so there is no contradiction. In order to prove the latter you would have to give a path $p : f(\mathtt{base}) = g(\mathtt{base})$ together with a homotopy $H$ witnessing that the square

commutes. This is not the case if $f \neq g$.
(In fact you don't even have $f(\mathtt{base}) = g(\mathtt{base})$ if $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary maps; you can only prove the mere equality $\| f(\mathtt{base}) = g(\mathtt{base}) \|$. The equality holds if $f$ and $g$ are pointed maps.)

Thanks. I'm not understanding your first comment.  Doesn't $x : S^1$ imply $x = \mathtt{base}$ meaning $f(\mathtt{base}) = \mathtt{base} = g(\mathtt{base})$ which is sufficient to have that, for all $x:S^1$, $f(x)=g(x)$ as witnessed by $\mathtt{refl}$?

No. Given $x : S^1$ you only have $| x = \mathtt{base} |$. The circle is connected but not contractible. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454548/why-isnt-s1-contractible-in-homotopy-type-theory

Ok, so is the issue that we don't have $f(x) = g(x)$ for arbitrary maps because it cannot be continuously realized, while $||f(x) = g(x)||$ can?

Yes, that's one way to think about it.
